# Como transformar este array?

Tags: php, array

Tenho um formulário que em certos campos me retorna várias possibilidades de dados em um único índice quando faço print do `array`. Esta situação pode ser vista nos `índices 3, 4, 5 e 7`.

```
Array
(
    [0] => APARTAMENTO
    [1] => CASA
    [2] => CASA EM CONDOMINIO
    [3] => COBERTURA/COBERTURA HORIZONTAL
    [4] => CONJUNTO/SALA/LOJA
    [5] => FLAT/LOFT
    [6] => PREDIO COMERCIAL
    [7] => TERRENO/AREAS
)
```

Eu preciso chegar a este resultado em `PHP` para que então eu possa começar as minhas consultas no banco de dados:

```
Array
(
    [0] => APARTAMENTO
    [1] => CASA
    [2] => CASA EM CONDOMINIO
    [3] => COBERTURA
    [4] => COBERTURA HORIZONTAL
    [5] => CONJUNTO
    [6] => SALA
    [7] => LOJA
    [8] => FLAT
    [9] => LOFT
    [10] => PREDIO COMERCIAL
    [11] => TERRENO
    [12] => AREAS
)
```

Cheguei a este resultado com este formulário:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="tipo[]" value="APARTAMENTO" id="tp1">
<label for="tp1">Apartamento</label>

<input type="checkbox" name="tipo[]" value="CASA" id="tp2">
<label for="tp2">Casa</label>

<input type="checkbox" name="tipo[]" value="CASA EM CONDOMINIO" id="tp3">
<label for="tp3">Casa Condomínio</label>

<input type="checkbox" name="tipo[]" value="COBERTURA/COBERTURA HORIZONTAL" id="tp4">
<label for="tp4">Cobertura</label>

<input type="checkbox" name="tipo[]" value="CONJUNTO/SALA/LOJA" id="tp5">
<label for="tp5">Conjunto/Sala/Loja</label>

<input type="checkbox" name="tipo[]" value="FLAT/LOFT" id="tp6">
<label for="tp6">Flat/Loft</label>

<input type="checkbox" name="tipo[]" value="PREDIO COMERCIAL" id="tp7">
<label for="tp7">Prédio Comercial</label>

<input type="checkbox" name="tipo[]" value="TERRENO/AREAS" id="tp8">
<label for="tp8">Terreno/Área</label>
```

Passando somente isso como instrução:

```
$tipo = $_GET['tipo'];
```

Por questões de layout, não posso fazer com que estes campos sejam diferentes, tipo `um tipo por input`. Alguma ideia??

Comment: Depende de como você está agrupando. Talvez um loop + explode na / resolva, mas acho que está agrupando errado.

Comment: Você precisa mostrar o código/consulta que gera `item1/item2`, como é esse formulário? Como chegou a essa array?. . . . 
 Se me permite um pequena critica, noto que geralmente falta esse tipo de informação nas suas perguntas.

Comment: Já que está agrupando no campo `value="OPÇÃO 1/OPÇÃO 2"`, um loop resolve. Outra solução seria montar via JS com cmapos ocultos.

Comment: Não sei como fazer tratamento de `arrays`, podem me dar um caminho??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Uma forma simples seria usando implode na array usando `'/'` e depois transformando em array com explode `'/'`. Joguei agora no [**ideone**](http://ideone.com/LYAIIA).

```
$array = array(
0 => 'APARTAMENTO',
1 => 'CASA',
2 => 'CASA EM CONDOMINIO',
3 => 'COBERTURA/COBERTURA HORIZONTAL',
4 => 'CONJUNTO/SALA/LOJA',
5 => 'FLAT/LOFT',
6 => 'PREDIO COMERCIAL',
7 => 'TERRENO/AREAS',
);

print_r( explode( '/' , implode( '/' , $array ) ) );
// output abaixo
Array
(
    [0] => APARTAMENTO
    [1] => CASA
    [2] => CASA EM CONDOMINIO
    [3] => COBERTURA
    [4] => COBERTURA HORIZONTAL
    [5] => CONJUNTO
    [6] => SALA
    [7] => LOJA
    [8] => FLAT
    [9] => LOFT
    [10] => PREDIO COMERCIAL
    [11] => TERRENO
    [12] => AREAS
)
```

Comment: Agora que eu tenho a `array` posso fazer uma consulta SQL usando ela certo?? Obrigado pela ajuda.

Comment: Os poderes de implode() as vezes me assusta. Eu estava aqui pensando em algo com array_walk_recursive() e tal daí veio esse corte rápido feito ninja e... Vish...

Comment: Primeiro teste foi loop, depois vi que ia explodir a `/`, então resolvi implodir com ela para resolver os 2 problemas. E a sequencia fica pequenininha :)